# Why does this Python Try not catch an exception when the return value is assigned to a variable?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, try-catch

I've got a try block like so:

```
try:
   result = api.call_to_api(arg1, ar2)
except: ValueError
```

Which gets called via a unit test where api.call_to_api() is patched as following:

```
@patch('api.call_to_api')
def myTest(self, mock):
   mock.side_effect = [DEFAULT, ValueError]
   # test logic
```

In the test it does not catch the error. Rather, what happens is result gets assigned

However, when I change the try block to the following it does catch the error:

```
try:
   result = api.call_to_api(arg1, ar2)
   api.call_to_api(arg1, ar2)
except: ValueError
```

When the api.call_to_api() gets its own line there is no issue with the test. It successfully catches the error I have mocked and sends it down the exception path. When I inspect the values result is still receiving the '' value, and it does trigger the try on the specific line without the assignment.

Why does this Python Try not catch an exception when the return value is assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first block of code does not catch an exception because no exception is raised. When you write `mock.side_effect = [DEFAULT, ValueError]`, you tell the mock to return `DEFAULT` the first time it is called and `ValueError` the second time (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock)). In your second block of code, you call `api.call_to_api` twice. This means that `result` will get the value of the first element in `side_effect` (i.e., `DEFAULT`), and the second line is an expression which equates to `ValueError`.

Comment: OMG, I feel so stupid. So stupid I thought about deleting this, but someone else is going to come along and see this in ten years and be happy I didn't. Thank you for this.